# How to use SparkSQL to select rows in Spark DF based on multiple conditions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am relatively new to pyspark and I have a spark dataframe with a date column "Issue_Date". The "Issue_Date" column contains several dates from 1970-2060 (due to errors). From the spark dataframe, I have created a temp table from it and have been able to filter the data from year 2018. I would also like to include the data from year 2019 (i.e., multiple conditions).  Is there a way to do so? I've tried many combinations but couldn't get it. Any form of help is appreciated, thank you.

```
# Filter data from 2018
sparkdf3.createOrReplaceTempView("table_view")
sparkdf4 = spark.sql("select * from table_view where year(to_date(cast(unix_timestamp(Issue_Date,'MM/dd/yyyy') as timestamp))) = 2018")

sparkdf4.count()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using `year(Issue_Date) >= 2018`?:

```
sparkdf4 = spark.sql("select * from table_view where year(to_date(cast(unix_timestamp(Issue_Date,'MM/dd/yyyy') as timestamp))) >= 2018")
```

If your column has errors, and you want to specify a range you can use `year IN (2018, 2019)`:

```
sparkdf4 = spark.sql("select * from table_view where year(to_date(cast(unix_timestamp(Issue_Date,'MM/dd/yyyy') as timestamp))) in (2018, 2019)")
```

Comment: i forgot to mention that the "Issue_Date" has errors and has dates that go up to 2070. So the >= 2019 might not work